# Setup commands for Mesos and Kubernetes on Docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, mesos

When trying to move a web container (Tomcat) to the latest technologies for better growth and support, I came across this [blog](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.ch/2014/08/mesosphere-collaborates-with-kubernetes-and-google-cloud-platform.html).  This part seems ideal for my needs:

> ... we are also incorporating Kubernetes into Mesos to manage the deployment of Docker workloads. Together, we provide customers with a commercial-grade, highly-available and production-ready compute fabric.

Now, how to setup a local test environment to try this out?  All these technologies seem interchangable!  I can run docker on mesos, mesos on docker, etc etc etc.  [Prepackaged](https://google.mesosphere.com/) instances allow me to run on others Clouds.  [Other videos also make this seem great!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXcdHwQ5GgQ&list=PL69nYSiGNLP0Ljwa9J98xUd6UlM604Y-l&sns=em)   Running out on the cloud is not a viable (allowed) option for me.  Unfortunately, I can not find 'instructions' on how to setup the configuration described/marketed/advertised.

If I am new to these technologies, and know there will be a learning curve,  is there a way to get initialized for doing such a "simple task": running a tomcat container on a Docker machine that is running Mesos/Kubernetes?  That is, without spending days trying to learn and figure out each individual part!  This is the picture from the blog site referenced:

[image]

Assuming that I "only" know how to create a docker container(s) (for say, centos-7).  What commands, in what order, (i.e. the secret 'code') do I need to use to configure small (2 or 3) local environment to try out running Tomcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I searched quite a bit, apparently not enough!  Someone pointed me to this:

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/mesos-docker.md

which is pretty close to exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: As the author of the linked guide, I think that's a great place to start experimenting! That's the setup we use for Mesosphere's continuous integration of Kubernetes on Mesos. It's also what we use when developing locally. It uses docker-in-docker to emulate multiple Mesos nodes, which can each run a containerized Kubernetes node.

Comment: If you'd like to setup a more realistic production environment, however, I recommend looking at the [Mesos guide](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/mesos.md) or the [new DCOS guide](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/dcos.md).

It's also worth noting that Kubernetes on Mesos is still in *alpha*. You can find our upcoming release milestones in the [Kubernetes-Mesos github project](https://github.com/mesosphere/kubernetes-mesos/milestones).